# Web app "taking" control of pc

Tags: java, web-applications

I wanto to build a simple e-learning web app, allowing students to only execute/access resources directly related to the current lesson, so they can stay focused. So the idea is this web app somehow becames "the only" app the student has access to, not being even able to use the operating system (windows 8).
I wonder if this is even possible.
Thx in advance.

Comment: I sincerely hope something like this will never become possible.

Comment: I think even a native app can't do that, let alone a webapp.

Answer (score 0):

No, a web app CANNOT take control of a PC.  If it can, there is a big security hole and it need to be fixed right away.

In your case, you don't need a web app to take control of the PC.  You only need a way so that students can't easily exit the learning application.  The cheapest way is to look into browser full screen mode, hide menu bar etc, so that students can only see education content.  This is what older version of learning application does.  However, newer browsers has too much help for user to get out of full screen mode.